# Preprocessor and whitespaces rules

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am interested in defining my own language inside a C++ block (lets say for example main) and for that purpose I need to use the preprocessor and its directives my problem relies to the below rule:

```
#define INSERT create() ...
```

Is called a function-like definition and preprocessor does not allow any whitespaces in what we define ,

So when I use a function of my own language I got to parse right handy the below statement:

```
INSERT INTO variable_name VALUES(arg_list)
```

to a different two function calls lets say

```
insertINTO(variable_name) and valuePARSE(arg_list)
```

but since the preprocessor directive rules do not allow me to have whitespaces in my definition how I can reach the variable_name and then make the call to the first function call I want to achieve?

Any clues would be helpful.

PS: I tried using g++ -E file.cpp to see how preprocessor works and to adjust the syntax to be valid c++ rules.

Comment: This doesn't sound too wise... or practical, for that matter.

Comment: It's not a matter of wisdom syntax has to be like stated above the thing is how to be able to get to the variable name :/ ,thanks .

Comment: Don't use the pre-processor for this. Its not designed for that kind of precessing.

Comment: I believe you would be better writing a compiler or translator for your language.  Perhaps a scripting or more text orient language like SNOBOL, Python, or Perl would be better.  As others have said, the preprocessor was not designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor included with most C++ compilers is probably way too weak for this kind of task. It was never designed for this kind of abuse. The boost preprocessor library could help you on the way, but I still think you're heading down a one-way street here.

If you really want to define your language this way, I suggest you either write your own preprocessor, or use one that is more powerful than the default one. [Here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/521902-using-python-as-a-c-preprocessor/) is one chap who tried using Python as a C++ preprocessor.

Comment: i dont think it's that complex :/ anyway thanks a lot for your time i will look into what you stated :)

Answer (score 0):

1) `define INSERT create()` is not a function-like macro it's object-like, something like `define INSERT(a, b, c) create(a, b, c)` would be;

2) if you want to expand `INSERT INTO variable_name VALUES(arg_list)` into `insertINTO(variable_name); valuePARSE(arg_list);` you can do something like:

```
#define INSERT insertINTO(
#define INTO 
#define VALUES(...) ); valueParse(__VA_ARGS__);
```

3) as you can see macros get ugly pretty easy and even the slightest error in your syntax will have you spend a lot of time tracking it down

4) since it's tagged C++ take a look at [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/proto.html) or [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer function-like or object like is not a problem , the real problem is the whitespaces that must not be included into definitions the thing still is how to get at the variable name that follows the INTO , Thanks for reply.

Comment: @gchatzip: You cannot get the variable name that follows with a object-like macro. You'll need to close the parenthesis using the next macro. For instance INSERT opens it (`#define INSERT insertINTO(`) and VALUES closes the it (`#define VALUES(...) ); valueParse(__VA_ARGS__);`).